# android - bookmark in epub reader?

Tags: android, webview, epub

I am developing epub reader using epublib. I want to add bookmark functionality in it. Any clues how to add it ?
also, 
What properties of webview do I need to get text from webview not using emulateShiftHeld() but directly. 
Also , where should I use findAll() of webview ?

Comment: Hi Rohit, Can you help me i am also doing same read .epub file,bookmarks,search things. Thanks in advance

Comment: @PrathameshTalathi Please create new post and ask specific questions there. I discontinued the epub reader, so I wont be able to help u :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bookmark for page in webview... Ok, If you are load page one by one then you can save the page URL for your bookmark or if you display whole pages at a once then In my case I used scroll position of webview, I just store the current scroll position of Webview and loaded page URL..

Comment: I have then 2nd case.. I checked the scroll position api. It ll do the work. but if the font size is changed then how you ll do that ?

Comment: In that case you have to store whole state, and i think you have to load the same style as when you store it as bookmark.

Comment: have you developed your own epub reader  ? coz u answered my previous question too :)

Comment: Do you have any website or anything where I can ask you directly instead of posting here ?

Comment: How do u implement search ? Any webview api is there ? i mean findAll() or something  ?

Comment: I am also working on same project, reading .epub file. I have referred this site http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib/android and able to read file but i want to read page one by one. can you help me.

Thanks in advance.